# May $p^3$ divide $(a+b)^p-a^p-b^p$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, experimental-mathematics

Do there exist positive integers $a,b$ and a prime $p>\max(a,b)$ such that $p^3$ divides $(a+b)^p-a^p-b^p$?

The reader of Kvant magazine A. T. Kurgansky asked to prove that such $a,b,p$ do not exist, see [here](http://kvant.mccme.ru/1984/08/p34.htm).
But discussion here

[On the exact reference of a cute Diophantine problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/255785/on-the-exact-reference-of-a-cute-diophantine-problem/255792?noredirect=1#comment630273_255792)

suggests that it should be very hard to prove. Maybe, a counterexample may be bound? Roughly speaking, a probability of this event is about $1/p^2$, for each $p$ we have about $p$ events (even for $b=1$, I was previously wrong that it may be supposed without loss of generality, thanks for Noam Elkies for noting this) and so as $\sum 1/p=\infty$, we may expect them (and even infinitely many!) But this series converges very slowly, so the minimal example may be large.

Comment: How far has it been checked numerically?  Computing power is much more plentiful now than it was in 1984.

Comment: That does not preserve congruences mod $p^3$.

Comment: "We may suppose that $b=1$" -- I don't see it:
replacing $(a,b)$ by $(a/b,1) \bmod p^2$ won't usually
preserve the region $a,b \leq p$.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies you are correct: of course, we can not assume this. Moreover, finding a root $x$ of $((x+1)^p-x^p-1)/p$ modulo $p^2$, if it exists, we may choose a pair $(a,b)=(a\mod p^2,ax \mod p^2)$ for appropriate $a$, and something like that works or almost works by Thue's lemma.

Comment: @AlexeyUstinov what exactly is the question? Of course we may always add $p^3$ to $a,b$.

Comment: I've now tested whether $(a+b)^p-a^p-b^p$ can be divisible by $p^6$ (when $p>\max(a,b)$) for the first 2000 primes, and in that range the answer is no.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are apparently lots of examples.  The smallest is $a=1$, $b=2$, and $p=7$.

Comment: The *cutest* small example was $a=5$, $b=6$, and $p=7$.

Comment: Great. I did not expect that they missed such a small example.

Comment: *Pace* **Pace Nielsen**, arguably $(a,b,p) = (3,5,7)$ is even cuter,
besides being the first example where $(a+b)^p - a^p - b^p$ is divisible
not just by $p^3$ but even by $p^5$.

Comment: Wow -- computers must have been pretty rubbish in 1984...

Answer (score 20):

We explain the pattern observed by **Joe Silverman**, deducing
the existence of infinitely many solutions, some of which even have
$p^5 | (a+b)^p - a^p - b^p$.

**Lemma.** *If $n \equiv 1 \bmod 3$ then the homogeneous polynomial
$P_n(a,b) := (a+b)^n - a^n - b^n \in {\bf Z}[a,b]$ has a factor $(a^2+ab+b^2)^2$.*

*Proof* :  Either
i) evaluate $P_n(x,1)$ and its derivative at a cube root of unity $\rho$, or
ii) use the $S_3$ symmetry of $-P_n(a,b) = a^n + b^n + c^n$ where $a+b+c=0$:
double roots at $(a:b:c) = (1:\rho:\rho^2)$ and $(1:\rho^2:\rho)$
are the only ways to get the total number of roots to be $1 \bmod 3$. $\Box$

[These ${\bf Q}(\rho)$-rational points on the $n$-th Fermat curve 
are well known.]

**Corollary.** *If $p$ is a prime congruent to $1 \bmod 3$,
and $a,b$ are integers such that $p^k | a^2+ab+b^2$, then
$p^{2k+1} | P_n(a,b)$.*

*Proof* : Observe that $P_p \in p {\bf Z}[a,b]$ and use the Lemma.

Now $k=1$, and thus $2k+1=3$, is easy to obtain:
choose $a$ arbitrarily, and let $b\equiv ra \bmod p$ where $r$ is a cube root of unity
mod $p$.  We can even get a factor of $p^5$ by choosing $a,b$ such that
$a^2 + ab + b^2 = p^2$ (that is, so that $a,b,p$ are sides of
a triangle with a $120^\circ$ angle); for example,
$$
(3+5)^7 - 3^7 - 5^7 = 120 \cdot 7^5.
$$

Comment: Yes of course (or as we'd do it nowadays, by applying Hensel's Lemma), but once $k>2$ we can no longer find positive solutions with $a,b < p$ as the Kvant problem asked.

Comment: For the first 200 primes I find by exhaustive search that there is no solution mod $p^6$ with $0<a,b<p$.

Comment: Motivated by Neil's computation, I've now checked all primes up to $8803$, and there are still no solutions modulo $p^6$.

Answer (score 10):

For what it's worth, consider $b=p-1$. It seems (experimentally at least, I haven't tried to prove it) that for every $p\equiv1\pmod6$ there exists an $a$ in the range $2\le a\le \frac{1}{2}p$ such that 
$$(a+p-1)^p-a^p-(p-1)^p\equiv0\pmod{p^3}.\qquad (*)$$
I checked for $p<500$, and in this range, for each $p$ there is a unique such $a$.
Further, again just for $p<500$, if $p\not\equiv1\pmod6$, then there are no solutions to $(*)$.

Comment: The unique solution is always a cube root of unity mod $p$ (verified up to $1000$ now); presumably it's easy to prove in general that this works, and intractable to show that there are no other solutions.

Comment: (Actually that was for $b=1$.  For $b=p-1$ it's a sixth root of unity.)

Comment: Interesting. This congruence is equivalent to $(a-1)^p-a^p+1\equiv 0\pmod p^3$, or $a+a^2/2+\dots+a^{p-1}/(p-1)\equiv 0 \pmod p^2$. But I do not see why it has roots modulo $p^2$ so often and why $p$ modulo 3 matters.

Comment: Well, why the cubic root of unity works is seen from this formula.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Thanks. I was going to try to figure out what the $a$ was when I got a chance. I'm not actually convinced of the uniqueness.

Comment: @FedorPetrov I don't see the equivalence. For example, $(p-1)^p$ and $(-1)^p$ are not the same modulo $p^3$, since $$(p-1)^p-(-1)^p\equiv p^2\pmod{p^3}.$$

Comment: Use binomial expansion: $(a-1+p)^p\equiv (a-1)^p+p^2(a-1)^{p-1}\equiv (a-1)^p+p^2$, $(p-1)^p\equiv p^2-1$ (as you say), so it is.

Comment: @FedorPetrov I see, I was just looking at the two terms separately.